# What are the software metrics used in solo programming?

Tags: metrics

I'm new in the field of software productivity metrics, and I'm looking for software metrics which improve solo programmer productivity

- What are software productivity metrics?
- What are the parameters that I should measure, and how to do that?
- What is the difficulty with traditional software development?

I have to cover all these questions as soon as possible

Answer (score 2):

As a developer productivity metric I suggest to consider following:

1. stability of developers contribution (that is how much of developers code has been rewritten afterwords by other developers)
2. percentage of developers code covered by unit tests
3. defect density (number of defects per 1,000 new or changed lines of code)